# How to ensure that messages with the same Person Id are executed in singleton fashion while different ones are executed in Parallel?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an `azure function` which I want to process multiple messages in `parallel` but such that messages with the same `Person Id` are executed in `singleton` manner.

**Scenario 1:**
I have `n` number of messages each having the same `Person Id`. Every message needs to be executed in the sequence they arrived but in a `singleton` fashion.

**Scenario 2:**
I have `n` number of messages. Some of them have `Person Id:1`. Some of them have `Person Id:2`. Messages with different Person Ids can be executed in `parallel` but messages with same `Person Id` needs to be executed in the sequence they arrived and in a `singleton` fashion.

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:**
My app is running on `Consumption Plan`, therefore, I cannot predict how and when my app will scale. An azure function initially acquires lease on all partitions. It appears that azure function acquires a lease on all the partition initially when the app is not scaled. The solution suggested by @juunas in comments worries me that my app will never scale and might end up running batches sequentially by a single instance of azure function because my function will not receive millions of data points consistently. The heuristics for scaling under `Consumption Plan` are not known.

Perhaps, somehow combining the event hub in ordered guarantee with durable functions parallel pattern?

**Edit 2:**

Consider two functions:

1. `Appender` Function: Maintains an ordered list in `cache` by appending Person Id along with any other required attribute. Not necessarily an azure function.
2. `Processor` Function: Use durable function [singleton pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-singletons) (can also store the information about Person Id being processed in `cache`)

**Flow:**

1. `Appender`, after appending, sends a message to a `queue` with just the `Person Id` in the message. The `Person Id` will be used as `instance id` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-singletons).
2. `Processor`, if an instance of the function does not already exist, will start executing the specific `Person Id` messages in the cache.
3. If an instance of the `Processor` already exists, the message will be ignored.

**Problem:**

A scenario in which `Processor` has completely emptied the cached `Person Id` ordered message but in parallel `Appender` appends another message before `Processor` exits so the new message is not executed. Now, the cache will contain 1 message unprocessed and no azure function will be called to process it until the `Appender` appends another message of the same `Person Id`.

Maybe, I should use `Durable Function` `Monitor` pattern somehow?

**Edit 3:**
Another approach I considered was the use of Monitor pattern. Instead of the message being ignored if the function with a specific `instance id` is being executed, it would wait in intervals. The queue message itself would just be `Person Id` with its other attributes placed in an ordered sequence in `cache`. This will ensure that every message is executed in the correct sequence (by using the list maintained in the `cache`). However, the following problem as mentioned in singleton [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-singletons) can occur when using monitor approach along with queue as:

> There is a potential race condition in this sample. If two instances
>   of HttpStartSingle execute concurrently, both function calls will
>   report success, but only one orchestration instance will actually
>   start. Depending on your requirements, this may have undesirable side
>   effects. For this reason, it is important to ensure that no two
>   requests can execute this trigger function concurrently.

Another approach, I considered was the use of Monitor pattern for executing only one message per function by combining the **Edit 2** `Appender` approach along with singleton pattern using instance id.

Comment: Have you looked at event hubs? It doesn't perfectly solve the problem, but you can always process a single partition's messages in order, while processing multiple partitions in parallel.

Comment: @juunas It won't guarantee that messages with same `Person Id` are not executed in parallel.

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428

Comment: @juunas This sounds good but suggests to have 2,147,483,647 partitions (max size of an `int` id). Doesn't it?

Comment: You can't have that many partitions also in event hubs. Like I said, it isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: @juunas Maybe I can use a different partition key than `Person Id`. e.g having one partition for even `Person Id` and one for odd `Person Id`. What do you think?

Comment: I think you can use the id, and use 32 partitions. The data will be split to 32 parts, but all messages for a person will always be in the same partition

Comment: @juunas I have edited the question according to your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put work items into a database. Each time a new work item is added also enqueue an Azure function invocation.

That Azure function will then sequentially process all queued work items for that person. It will query the database to get *all* work for that person, not just any work.

There must be a mechanism that ensures that only one Azure function call is running at any point in time for a particular person. You can do this by implementing some form of lock. For example, you could write to a database table the information that person 1234 is currently being processed. If an Azure function is invoked with person 1234 and it notices that this person is already being processed it would simply return and do nothing.

This scheme that I just proposed has a few holes in it such as race conditions. But those can be fixed. I hope this idea will get you started solving the problem.

I guess the meta mistake here is to insist on solving the problem with functions, queues or other Azure primitives. A normal database (e.g. Azure tables or SQL) does the job.

Comment: Had thought of a solution similar to this. Please see Edit 2. Thanks

Comment: @tehmas I am not too familiar with Azure functions. Does this solution ensure that there will always be a function running after a new work item arrives? What happens, when the last instance is about to exit and `StartNewAsync` is called? Does it then make sure that the exiting function is made running again?

Comment: It ensures that only a single instance for the same Person Id is executing. It has a problem in which it wouldn’t be running as stated in the question detail **Edit 2**.

Comment: Added another similar approach in **Edit 3** but it still has a problem.

Comment: @tehmas in your edit 3, I do not understand the concern following "However...". If only one invocation actually performs work that is as designed. The problem is, rather, that the only executing instance might fail (due to bug, IO error, Azure abort, ...). So you need a mechanism to eventually process work where all function invocations failed. This can be solved completely with a background job that enqueues all outstanding work that is older than some time limit. Redundantly enqueing is always safe. Would that not work? This is so simple that I would not bother with "advanced" Azure features

Comment: Edit 2 approach: The one invocation which is actually performing work needs to exit at some point (B) after checking at some point (A) if there are no items remaining to be processed. If a message arrives in between point A and B, it would not be processed because the existing function is exiting and no new function can be called because an invocation of the function already exists. Edit 3 approach: tried to remedy the problem by using monitor (intervals) such that an invocation of function processes one message in cache only. The race condition mentioned will cause Edit 3 approach to fail.

Comment: @tehmas and what about the background process that re-enqueues old work items? That should fix any and all races. I think you need such a background job anyway because function invocations can fail for any number of reasons.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by "re-enqueues old work items". Such a background job would need to run forever after regular intervals of time.

Comment: @tehmas yes, it would query the work item table forever every x seconds. Polling can be a great solution. It is very simple, very robust, it's restartable in case of error, can be run on demand, does not depend on any specific schedule or trigger and usually it is possible to make it cheap. Azure functions has timer triggers, right?

Comment: Azure Function do have timers and monitors but I think we can resolve this by launching another azure function which checks after some seconds, only once, if our primary function needs to be started again. If another message arrives in the meantime, it would start the process otherwise this would start it instead. This seems to remove the deadlock problem while avoiding polling. What do you think?

Comment: @tehmas it seems very brittle to have these functions watching themselves. If the chain ever breaks off work items will remain unprocessed forever. No human will notice, either. Failures can occur for many reasons and sometimes bugs cause long series of failures. Also, the complexity of this solution is far too high for my taste. It seems like a bad design to have these elaborate graphs of functions all starting each other (sometimes in a cycle even). Hard to develop, to debug, to maintain and to operate.

Comment: That said it seems this design would work except for the case that all queued functions fail. Then, the system will be in a permanently broken state until human intervention.

Comment: I agree regarding the scenario if all queued functions fail. If they fail, I actually want to discard them. On exception I can remove them from cache. If somehow cache is not accessible, maybe I can use a time-triggered function which runs let's say after every 6 hours to remove expired messages from cache.